# H2 and Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, h2

Is it possible to use a H2 database file in Micorsoft Access and how can I make this? What kind of Driver do I need and where can I download it?

I try to open a H2 database file with the H2 console and always get the "out of memory" error message and maybe Microsoft Access can help now.

With regards..

Answer (score 0):

H2 says that "it supports the PostgreSQL network protocol. Therefore, the PostgreSQL ODBC driver can be used." (ref: [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#odbc_driver)). It also says:

> Support for the PostgreSQL network protocol is quite new and should be viewed as experimental. It should not be used for production applications.